# Why catch Exception is not printed after catching NPE Exception

Tags: java

```
try {
     String x = null;
     int y = x.length();
} catch (NullPointerException npe) {
     System.out.println("NPE Exception ");
} catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Exception ");
}
```

Above piece of code print only "NPE Exception" in output and not "NPE Exception Exception". Can any one please explain as NPE is a type of RunTimeException and we know RunTimeException is a subtype of Exception class?

Comment: Because the `catch (NullPointerException npe)` is triggered. Think of `catch` like a `case` with `break`s.

Comment: NPE already means NullPointerException. Therefore the "... NPE Exception" in your title is redundant and should just be "NPE" or, better, "NullPointerException".

Answer (score 7):

Any `Throwable` is caught only once,the first catch block which can handle an exception

Answer (score 3):

Becase you can catch **your** exception only once or if you want to go to the next catch the rethrow your exception and catch it again. From [Java7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) you can catch like this alse:

```
catch( NullPointerException | SQLException ex ) { 
  System.out.println("NPE Exception ");
```

Multi-Catch blocks provide you with an cleaner way of handling exceptions preventing code duplication across several catch blocks.However,note that Exceptions which are peer to each other can only be put in multi-catch block.

Comment: You can re-throw your exception and catch it more than once ;)

Comment: @KumarAbhinav:- Good pick! Thanks

Comment: @KumarAbhinav:- I have just given an option which is added and it is not bad to give those. Thanks